# How to access certain part of a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, split, strsplit

I have a string which looks like this:

```
0,1,488,332,165;1,1,553,712,206;2,1,803,1248,219;3,1,2222,1285,398
```

The actual string is way more longer than this ...

I need to access the `488`, `553`, `803` and `2222` but the problem is that these values change.

I don't want to index it because the string is about 1000 characters long.

Comment: split by ; split each by , use third - no way aound it. you need toi iterate the string. you could throw away any letter that comes before the second "," - take anything up to the third "," discard anythng up to next ";" then repeat.

Comment: What do you mean, "these values change"? Their positions? Or the values you're trying to extract?

Comment: i think it is the values that he is trying to estract.

Comment: @ddejohn on the same place, there can be different value every time ...

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Are there ALWAYS 5 values between ;  - is it always  the THIRD value you want? What are the rules? Are there exceptions?

Comment: Yes there's always 5 values between `;` and I always want the third value after the `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `list` comprehension, and string's `split` method, to wrap this up in:

```
result = [x.split(",")[2] for x in string.split(';')]
```

Comment: `result = [x.split(",")[2] for x in m.split(';')]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: would be great !

Comment: if there are 5 values and the 3rd value is always there , then it is impossibile that it gives you `IndexError`, maybe you missed a comma, or a semicolen, but this answer only works if the commas in the space between the semicolens are exactly 5.

Comment: yeah but in this case there are 4 commas between the semicolen

Comment: have solved it finally